# Fit a curve with a SIR model and predict

Tags: python, ode

I have searched and referenced the code for solving the SIR model from others on this website, but the fitting effect is very poor. Is there something wrong with my data? Still what? How should I predict given new data for this SIR model?

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import integrate, optimize
    import pandas as pd
    
    y_total = [0.0, 0.0010131712259371835, 0.0035460992907801418, 0.00911854103343465,
        0.008611955420466059, 0.021783181357649443, 0.00911854103343465, 0.07852077001013172, 0.4397163120567376, 
        0.21681864235055726, 0.232016210739615, 0.5278622087132725, 0.13576494427558258, 0.2988855116514691, 0.37436676798378926, 
        0.4209726443768997, 0.544579533941236, 0.7254305977710233, 1.0, 0.7740628166160081, 0.43617021276595747, 0.48226950354609927]
    
    x_total = range(0,22)
    ydata = np.array(y_total, dtype=float)
    xdata = np.array(x_total, dtype=float)
    
    # IO + SO + R0 is always 1 regardless of "value"
    I0 = 0.3
    S0 = 1 - I0
    R0 = 0
    
    def sir_model(y, x, beta, gamma):
        S = -beta * y[0] * y[1] / N
        R = gamma * y[1]
        I = -(S + R)
        return S, I, R
    
    def fit_odeint(x, beta, gamma):
        return integrate.odeint(sir_model, (S0, I0, R0), x, args=(beta, gamma))[:,1]
    
    N = 1.0
    I0 = ydata[0]
    S0 = N - I0
    R0 = 0.0
    
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_odeint, xdata, ydata)
    fitted = fit_odeint(xdata, *popt)
    
    plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')
    plt.plot(xdata, fitted)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your `I0` is the first data element which is zero. Thus the solution stays at the equilibrium `(S,I,R)=(1,0,0)`. Make `I0` a variable parameter and include it in the fitting variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the initial infected number also a variable, which is easily done by shift the computation of the initial state into the target function

```
    
    def sir_model(y, x, beta, gamma):
        N = sum(y)
        S = -beta * y[0] * y[1] / N
        R = gamma * y[1]
        I = -(S + R)
        return S, I, R
    
    def fit_odeint(x, beta, gamma, I0):
        # IO + SO + R0 is always 1 regardless of "value"
        S0 = 1 - I0
        R0 = 0
        return integrate.odeint(sir_model, (S0, I0, R0), x, args=(beta, gamma))[:,1]
        
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_odeint, xdata, ydata,(1/5,1/8,0.1))
```

There were some other changes, especially adding an initial guess to `curve_fit`. Still this gets a warning on some difficulty in `odeint`. But a result is reached anyway, with `popt = [0.36714402, 0.04176973, 0.01311579]`, `1/popt = [2.72372678, 23.94078424, 76.2439491]`. Changing the initial guess to values close to this, `(1/3, 1/24, 0.05)`, eliminates the warning.

[image]